# django : How to create & call a Constructor on every request?

Tags: python, django, validation, default-constructor

I want to call a request validator method every time a `POST` request is called.

So Code I want to have like :

```
import validator

class ViewClass():
    def __CONSTRUCTOR__(self, request):
        is_valid = validator.validate()
        if is_valid == FALSE
           return HttpResponse('Request is Invalid')

    def request_function_one(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return HttpResponse('Request 1 is Valid')

    def request_function_two(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return HttpResponse('Request 2 is Valid')
```

How can I achieve this using django ?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#middleware

Comment: `ViewClass` is a subclass of a `DetailView`, (or something similar)?

Comment: I find it a bit strange that you encode such `request_function_one`s into such class, this is not how class-based views are typically used.

Comment: In fact the whole idea of a class-based view is that it exposes some functions like `.get(..)`, `.post(..)` but you should not link those to a view directly. By using `.as_view(..)` you basically implement a routing mechanism that will fetch the parameters, make some queries, and then you have a convenient `.get(..)` function where you write the specific logic (without much noise).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I have created functions like `viewData`, `updateData`, `listData` which I am showing as `request_function_one`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, `ViewClass` is I am referring to `views.py` has class named `ViewClass(View)`

Comment: Well this is simply not how the `View` should be used. A view is used for routing, for fetching objects, sometimes for rendering, etc. Not to group view functions together. After all, in Python you can write independent functions (and therefore independent utility functions like `viewData`, `updateData`, `listData`, etc.).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, You are right, But now I want to validate each request before these methods are called, like in constructor etc.. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really really  want to do it in django - I recommend to look on http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

You will not be dissapointed by power of validators in this framework.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/

Comment: Hm. I suppose that I answered for your needs but not for your question "as is".